# Ruby gem for microphone and speaker

Tags: ruby, audio, microphone

I'm working on a program for group audio chat on a local network(which helps students in a classroom to talk in random group, not always the students next to them).

It just went smoothly til I can not find a gem to get access to the Microphone and Speaker. Some one suggests I could win32 api on windows, or some shell command on Linux. But I hope that I can do it with ruby if possible.

Could someone give me a solution base on ruby gem to get access to the microphone and speaker?
If I miss any necessary detail for you, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Ruby-PortAudio](https://github.com/jvoorhis/ruby-portaudio)

> This package contains Ruby bindings to the PortAudio api. PortAudio is a cross-
>   platform interface to your audio hardware.
>
> The ruby-portaudio package supports both PortAudio apis: blocking and
>   non-blocking. The blocking API allows Ruby scripts to iteratively fill a
>   sample buffer which is then written to the audio hardware (later versions will
>   also support reading from a buffer). The non-blocking api allows Ruby programs
>   to act as controllers for audio streams defined by an external callback
>   function. Because the callback function may be run in an interrupt, it is not
>   really feasible to implement one in Ruby. You can, however, write your callback
>   function in a C extension, or you may build your own using LLVM or LibJIT as in
>   http://github.com/jvoorhis/Motivik.

Comment: Another PortAudio-related gem is https://github.com/nanki/ffi-portaudio